# Is it wrong to install event listener during onCreateView

Tags: android

I realize, sometimes installing event listener during `onCreateView` will not work. For instance, I take installing list view's click listener within `ListFragment` as an example

### Doesn't work

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // Won't work?! Listener will not be triggered.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewOnItemClickListener()); 
    // Installing long click listener does work somehow...
```

### Works!

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Works!
    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewOnItemClickListener());
```

I was wondering, is it wrong to install event listener during onCreateView? As I do not find this is being mentioned in documentation.

Comment: I think it's ok to set listener in onCreateView. I have button.setOnClickListener there and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not wrong to set listeners in onCreateView.
You code might have other problems. (need more details to say what wrong with your code.)

Below is the sample code that comes with Android SDK. (ContentFragment.java)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_welcome, null);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    mContentView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    // Handle drag events when a list item is dragged into the view
    mContentView.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
        public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    view.setBackgroundColor(
                            getResources().getColor(R.color.drag_active_color));
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    return processDragStarted(event);

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    return processDrop(event, imageView);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Show/hide the system status bar when single-clicking a photo.
    mContentView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentActionMode != null) {
              // If we're in an action mode, don't toggle the action bar
              return;
            }

            if (mSystemUiVisible) {
              setSystemUiVisible(false);
            } else {
              setSystemUiVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    // When long-pressing a photo, activate the action mode for selection, showing the
    // contextual action bar (CAB).
    mContentView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }

            mCurrentActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(
                    mContentSelectionActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return mContentView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends of what your logic needs, if you call getActivity() in your event listener logic then it should definitely be in onActivityCreated method (i.e. if you use progress dialog while loading something, Toast messages, AsyncTask with some logic in onPreExecute and onPostExecute) since only after onActivityCreated you can be sure that getActivity() won't return null, otherwise it will probably ok to set event listeners in onCreateView. Also don't use onAttach(Activity activity) for above mentioned logic, since in here we can only obtain reference to activity, which doesn't mean that activity that holds fragment is fully created and functional, it will be fully functional only after onActivityCreated is called